# Debugging issues with docking station

Tags: freeze, dock-station

Occasionally when I plug my Dell USB-C docking station into my laptop running Manjaro, the system immediately freezes completely and requires a hard reboot.

Other times, my external screens don't get detected until I unplug and replug the docking station. Keyboard and mouse always work though.

I've had these issues for quite some time and it's not just limited to Manjaro, I've had it with Ubuntu as well (both running KDE Plasma).

I'm running this on a brand new Dell XPS 13 laptop and experienced the same issues on a previous model.

Where do you typically look to start debugging issues like this? Which log files and/or tools would you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When freezing I'd use `journalctl -b -1`. It will show you the previous kernel messages until reboot.

In case of non detected screens, I'd look at `/var/log/Xorg0.log` or other Xorg*.log files. You might post the relevant part of the logs in your question.